# related to installation unable to understand partitioning

Tags: 14.04

While installing Ubuntu 14.04 server on VMware, it asks me for partition of the disk though I gave the 20 GB space on VMware initially. But it is [again asking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I6UH.png) for guided partitioning or occupy full disk space, which I am unable to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are done giving 20 GB space for partitioning purpose then it will do OOTB partitioning - allocating some space for root(/) and some for swap partition.
So you should move your mouse/keyboard cursor to "Finish partitioning and write changes to disk" and write the changes.